# How do I set a variable to a random integer in Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to coding and am now trying to build a rock paper scissors game in Python 3. Here is my code at the moment `

```
answer = input("To play: type in Rock (r), Paper (p) or Scissors (s)").lower()

if answer == "rock" or answer == "r":
    answer = 1
    print ("You chose Rock!")

elif answer == "paper" or answer == "p":
    answer = 2
    print ("You chose Paper!")

elif answer == "scissors" or answer == "s":
    answer = 3
    print ("You chose Scissors!")

else:
    print ("You didn't pick an option... Make sure you spell it right!")
    rps()

computer = lambda: random.randint(1, 3)
if computer == 1:
    string_computer = "Rock"
elif computer == 2:
    string_computer = "Paper"
elif computer == 3:
    string_computer = "Scissors"
else:
    print ("There must had been a glitch")
    rps()

if answer == computer:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so it\'s a draw!"))
elif answer == 1 and computer == 2:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so unfortuantely you lost."))
    rps()
elif answer == 1 and computer == 3:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so you won! Congratulations!"))
    rps()
elif answer == 2 and computer == 1:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so you won! Congratulations!"))
    rps()
elif answer == 2 and computer == 3:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so unfortuantely you lost."))
    rps()
elif answer == 3 and computer == 1:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so unfortuantely you lost."))
    rps()
else:
    print(("The computer chose"), string_computer,("so you won! Congratulations!"))
    rps()
```

`

And when I try to run the code, all syntaxes are correct but it comes up with "There must had been a glitch" which I added in to see if it wasnt chosing a number between 1 and 3. How do I fix it so it picks a number between 1 and 3 ?

Comment: Remove the `lambda:` and just have `computer = random.randint(1 ,3)`. Now you’re saying you want the variable to contain a function that calls the random, not a random value

Comment: You need to add `import random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

computer = random.randint(1,3)
```

there's no need for a lambda function here.

including the lambda function set `computer` to a function that will generate a random number between 1 and 3:

```
>>> computer = lambda: random.randint(1, 3)
>>> computer
<function <lambda> at 0x000001F4DD2738C8>
```

if you then call `computer()` you will get a random number between 1 and 3:

```
>>> computer()
2
>>> computer()
2
>>> computer()
1
```

for your functionality, getting rid of the `lambda:` is the best fix. If you are tempted to add parenthesis in the `if computer...` statements, you might end up in the `glitch` statement because you'll be generating a new random int for each `computer()` call.

Comment: @MyloBishop Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept this answer if it was solved you issue! It helps users determine which questions to look at. You can read more about accepting answers here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088